# Form without model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to let users select between two radio buttons, and then transfer that data to a controller where it will be used as a filter on a database. The filtered data from the database should then be displayed back on the page. 
My form

```
<%= form_tag do %>
<%= radio_button_tag(:sex, "male") %>
<%= label_tag(:male, "I am male") %>
<%= radio_button_tag(:sex, "female") %>
<%= label_tag(:female, "I am female") %>
<%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

But I am unsure on how I can achieve this. I have created a model "Countries" that refers to a database that have a list of countries and some statistics related to gender within that country. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you implement search functionality on the model "Countries".[Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=Search) has a few casts on the subject.

Comment: Isn't it possible to add the data from the form to a SQL query and use that to fetch the data directly?

Comment: When you submit a form, the fields of the form are sent to Rails as parameters.then you can reference the parameters in your controller to  to initialize the model with its respective attribute that is mapped on the respective database column.